# How to Create New File Everytime I Run The Program?

Tags: python

I want my code to create a new file every time the user registers a new username and password, they'll have their own file which will have all their data into that file.

My current code just re-writes the same file, is there a way to code so it creates a new file each time?

```
def register():
    print("To Register as a New Customer Create a New Username and Password")

    userDetails = open("user_details" , 'w')
    
    username = input("\nEnter Username: ")
    password = input("Enter Password: ")

    userDetails.write("\nUsername: " + username + "\n")
    userDetails.write("Password: " + password + "\n")

    userDetails.close()
     
register()
```

Comment: I suggest using the 'a' for append, as this will create a file if it does not exist, and if it exists, it will append the information to it. `userDetails = open("user_details" , 'a')`. Check this out for more info https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html , under section 7.2

Comment: Add the user's name to the file's name?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`uuid`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html) module to generate a unique id for every user and use that as a file name:

```
import uuid

def register():

    print("To Register as a New Customer Create a New Username and Password")

    username = input("\nEnter Username: ")
    password = input("Enter Password: ")

    file_name = f"{username}-{uuid.uuid4()}"

    userDetails = open(file_name , 'w')
    userDetails.write("\nUsername: " + username + "\n")
    userDetails.write("Password: " + password + "\n")
    userDetails.close()
    
register()
```

Ideally, you could just create a single file with details of all users as suggested by Irfan and have a unique id per user to distinguish them.